# MVC Not Installed

Tags: model-view-controller, visual-studio-2010

I have Visual Studio 10. I installed SP1 and I can not create an MVC web project. Is there anything else I need to install?

Comment: Are you trying `File -> New -> Project` or `File -> New -> WebSite`?

Comment: NVM I went to New -> Website. I do have the MVC option. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you will need to do use `File -> New -> Project` and under `Web` you should be able to see the MVC project templates.

*Reference: I encountered the same when I was just starting with MVC.*

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it looks as if you have the solution you're seeking, however I would like to mention for the sake of others that if you want to develop an MVC3 application on VS2010 SP1, you will still need to install it.

More details [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3).

I'm not aware of any good reason to not use MVC3 for new development, as it's contains many improvments over MVC2.